# Done button crashes app

Tags: swift

I wanted a way to dismiss a keyboard when I type in a UITextField. I looked it up on google, and found this on Medium:

https://medium.com/@KaushElsewhere/how-to-dismiss-keyboard-in-a-view-controller-of-ios-3b1bfe973ad1

Everytime I press the done button, the app crashes. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
   super.viewDidLoad()
   //init toolbar
   let toolbar:UIToolbar = UIToolbar(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0,  width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: 30))
   //create left side empty space so that done button set on right side
   let flexSpace = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem:    .flexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
   let doneBtn: UIBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: “Done”, style: .done, target: self, action: Selector(“doneButtonAction”))
   toolbar.setItems([flexSpace, doneBtn], animated: false)
   toolbar.sizeToFit()
   //setting toolbar as inputAccessoryView
   self.textField1.inputAccessoryView = toolbar
   self.textField2.inputAccessoryView = toolbar
}
func doneButtonAction() {
   self.view.endEditing(true)
}
```

Comment: `Selector(“doneButtonAction”)` should probably be `#selector(“doneButtonAction”)` and `func doneButtonAction() {` should probably be `@objc func doneButtonAction() {` depending on which version of Swift you're using

Comment: Do you have unnecessary IBOutlet connections in Storyboard?

Comment: use @objc in front of `func doneButtonAction()`

Comment: Please provide details of the crash. The stack trace or crash log would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add **`@objc`** to your `doneButtonAction` function as this is the reason why it's crashing. And use #selector instead of Selector.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    //init toolbar
    let toolbar:UIToolbar = UIToolbar(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0,  width: 
    self.view.frame.size.width, height: 30))
    //create left side empty space so that done button set on right side
    let flexSpace = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem:    .flexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
    let doneBtn: UIBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: .done, target: self, action: #selector(doneButtonAction))
    toolbar.setItems([flexSpace, doneBtn], animated: false)
    toolbar.sizeToFit()
    //setting toolbar as inputAccessoryView
    self.textField1.inputAccessoryView = toolbar
    self.textField2.inputAccessoryView = toolbar
}

@objc func doneButtonAction() {
    self.view.endEditing(true)
}
```